# Margin bottom on hover not working with masonry?

Tags: jquery, margin, masonry

I just wanna know if there's a way to recreate something like [this](http://elphinstonebasic.tumblr.com) (hover on the quote entry). I've been searching for hours now on how to create something like that but I can't really find an answer.

Here's my js:

`$(function () {
    var $container = $('#content');
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '#entry',
        columnWidth: 155
    });
});`

I don't know what else to add there for the `margin-bottom` to work when you hover on the `#entry`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umws6nrk/13/)

Please help? Thank you. xx

Comment: check here http://jsfiddle.net/nz5LG/1/

Comment: Do you have an example to show what/why is not working?

Comment: Here's my fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/umws6nrk/13/) and this -> [link](http://elphinstonebasic.tumblr.com/) (hover on the quote entry) - is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With masonry would be hard to accomplish the effect. I've made you a fiddle using salvattore.js http://jsfiddle.net/umws6nrk/16/

Works out of the box perfectly.

You just need the script added at the bottom of the body, and in css

```
#content[data-columns]::before {
    content: '2 .column.size-1of2';
}

/* These are the classes that are going to be applied: */
.column { float: left; }
.size-1of2 { width: 50%; }
```

Comment: I tried it here: [link](http://asphyxiated.tk) It seems to be working fine at first but when I got to the bottom, it was just one long column and not two. I did everything in the fiddle that you did. Now I don't know what's wrong with it. Should I send you my theme code?

Comment: Check the css for this
#content[data-columns]::before {
    content: '2 .column.size-1of2';
} In the fiddle it says 3, should be 2.

Comment: I changed it, but it's still like that. Well, not always, because whenever there is a photoset/video on a page, there's always a one long column at the bottom. I am using the sliding div when you hover on the photoset/video entries.